# Use requirejs in gruntjs to build a library, and use it in other projects

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs, grunt-contrib-requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I am building a library which is a set of folders containing Model View Controller Javascript files.
Each files has dependencies declared using require syntax:

```
define([
    'modules/moduleA/src/moduleAModel',
    'modules/moduleA/src/moduleAController',
], function(moduleAModel, moduleAController) {
    function moduleAView(param) {
        // ....
    }
```

I am compiling this library using GruntJS with the great "grunt-contrib-requirejs".
The problem is that as a library there is no entry point, no main.
I want users to be able to use it by calling each module when they need it.

Here are my questions:

**Firstly:**
How can I build one javascript file for the library which includes all the modules without declaring them one by one ?

**Secondly:**
How can I reuse this library later on another project ?
I tried this :

```
define(function(require) {
    var myLibrary = require('js/external-libs/myMinifiedLibrary.min');
    var moduleAV = new moduleAView();
```

But of course second lines fail, is there something like `require(myLibrary.moduleAView)` ?

What would you suggest ?

**Update:**
I found out that when you have minified on one single file all your modules, you have multiple defines on one page, this is interpreted as a script for requirejs and you have to load it twice ! (first time the whole file, second times your main).
Then my 'main' or entry point is built manually (which is still a problem) on rockerest answers.
So solution to my second question is on this post:
http://jaketrent.com/post/dynamically-require-optimized-modules-requirejs/

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite problem: I wanted users to pull the library and **not** have to know about each [internal](https://github.com/rockerest/ribcage/blob/master/src/region.js) [module](https://github.com/rockerest/ribcage/blob/master/src/layout.js).

To accomplish this, I created a single entry point that returns the [parent module](https://github.com/rockerest/ribcage/blob/master/src/layout.js). The parent then handles deferring to children as necessary.

[This file](https://github.com/rockerest/ribcage/blob/master/src/ribcage.js) is that entry point.

If I modified that file to return an object, each internal module would be available on the loaded library:

```
define(
    ["layout", "region"],
    function( Layout, Region ){
        return {
            "LayoutModule": Layout,
            "RegionModule": Region
        };
    }
);
```

I think this is what you want:

- the r.js optimizer builds everything into one file
- other code simply includes the library file (`require( "myLib" )`)
- each individual module is available on the response object (`myLib.LayoutModule`, `myLib.RegionModule`).

Comment: Really interesting, it answers my second questions, but still I would have to declare each module on the entry point. The problem of doing that is that I have a library core folder with many files, but also on each optionnal module I have a lot of files, Adding a new line each time I Want to add a module would broke the fact that my code is modular

Comment: @Tim It sounds like you're saying something like: "I want a dependency loader to load all my dependencies, but I don't want to have to define my dependencies!" Your code is still modular, but you have to SOMEHOW tell your library what modules it needs!

Comment: @SLTMikey I probably wasn't so clear, I don't want to define my dependencies 'manually' when I build my library, I want to have everything in one file. Also my depencies are well defined for each files, the problem is that I have a lot of files.
I want to be able to use those modules when I use this library.

Comment: @rockerest By the way, I don't succeed to use myLib.LayoutModule, I'm probably doing something wrong, should I use require optimizer with a sort of AMD wrap ?